# How do I change font in applications and desktop - Ubuntu 18

Tags: gnome, fonts, interface

Newbie here.

I installed gnome-tweek-tool and helped me to change fonts in most places. 
However, I can't change shown font in applications. Currently, in chrome, some apps, sites, desktop ubuntu render text in 'Ubuntu Monospace'(terminal default font) It's not Chrome issue. Font settings in chrome also don't have ubuntu monospace as active font.

And i can not find more font related options in gnome of default ubuntu settings. Monospace just horrible and hurts my eyes. 
[image]

Comment: I was hoping that my answer would have at least provided you some relief using Chrome; sorry it didn't help. Can you try another theme to see it that helps? I can't replicate this on my Ubuntu VM; I even have `Ubuntu Monospace` set as the monospace font.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's been a while, I might have an answer to this. I have PopOS 20.10 and had a similar problem recently, where all in-application fonts are reverted to a monospace font despite normal font settings in Settings and Tweaks. This happened when I removed all files in the directory /etc/fonts/conf.d/. When I restore the contents in this directory, the in-application fonts are back to normal and can be set through Tweaks.

I suspect (at least for my case) some connection was broken when a certain file is removed from conf.d/, but I don't have enough expertise to identify the specifics.

Sorry that I don't have more details to offer!